# Label on a tree edge to a node that has children

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have a problem when trying to label an edge that goes to a node that itself has children. Here is what I would like to do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {A}
    child { node {B} edge from parent [->] node [left] {\tiny 1} }
    child { node {C} edge from parent [->] node [right] {\tiny 2}
        child { node {D}  }
        child { node {E}  }
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This does not work because, it would appear, Tikz thinks D and E are children of my label. I have tried adding braces in different spots to no avail.

So I have attempted a different strategy, given that my labelling needs are not very complicated, and tried this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[act1/.code={\node [above=5mm] {\tiny 1};},
                    act2/.code={\node [above=5mm] {\tiny 2};}]
    \node {A}
    child { node {B} edge from parent [act1,->] }
    child { node {C} edge from parent [act2,->]
        child { node {D}  }
        child { node {E}  }
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`act1` gives just about the right result, but as soon as I use `act2`, the code refuses to compile and gives me an error message I am unable to make sense of:

`! Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.`

(with two spaces between "named" and "is")

Any information about how to do this without resorting to a different package would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is simply to move `edge from parent [->] node [right] {\tiny 2}` ***after*** the two "children" of `C`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {A}
    child { node {B} edge from parent [->] node [left] {\tiny 1} }
    child { node {C} 
        child { node {D}  }
        child { node {E}  }
        edge from parent [->] node [right] {\tiny 2}
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]